# Windows corrupted folder showing infinite size and infinite number of files

Tags: windows

I woke up with a bluescreen which is not uncommon for whatever reason (truecrypt probably). Apparently in an Eclipse project's classes folder, a package folder is being displayed by windows as having an ever increasing number of files (when viewing folder properties, the files never stop growing) with the size on disk being multiple terrabytes. It's not possible to delete this folder or view its contents. It says:

Cannot delete ges-table.es. Cannot find the specified file.

This is in a mounted TrueCrypt file.

This is related to:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651815/eclipse-javaw-exe-hanging-at-startup-49-cpu-regardless-of-task

**My question is how to delete this folder.**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The fact you are getting so many bluescreens should concern you.  I have been on Vista/Windows 7 for nearly 5 years, and not recieved a single bluescreen, track down the reason for them.

Comment: My question is how to delete this folder.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers never stopping counting up do not mean the file is an infinite size, it just means Windows hasn't yet finished counting the size and contents.

It appears as though some sort of loop in the Eclipse or TrueCrypt programs is creating these files and the way to stop it and remove the file is to end these processes.

You could reboot into Safe Mode and try deleting the file that way, or you could run ProcExplorer from Sysinternals, search for the folder name and find the process that is holding that folder hostage, end the process tree, and delete the folder.

UPDATE for added information from OP:

Windows has rules as to what characters can and cannot be used in folder and file names. If the code was dumped as files and folders, you're probably dealing with a large number of invalid file names that Windows has no idea what to do with. You'll probably need to use a Live CD (ubuntu or the like) to boot into a non-Windows environment and then delete the files.

Comment: TrueCrypt can't be launched in safe mode. I doubt a process is involved with this but I'll check. This occurs after a restart. I know it's not an infinite size, I am stating the symptoms.

Comment: If TrueCrypt is locking the file and so it not running is what you'll want to happen so that you can delete the files.

Comment: Could you restate what you said I dont think it makes sense grammatically/sentense structure, I'm not sure what you mean. Also, I have found out what happened. Eclipse wrote the contents of the files in this folder (ie Java code) as file names. So, cygwin is showing a bunch of files that are named like: field=e.typ, java.lan.g.r, bits of code written as the file names. I dont know how to delete them though. Some files ls is not able to access and for the ones it's displaying, it's not able to register a size for them or any other metadata.

Comment: Deleting with del /f * gets me: The system cannot find the file specified.